# RESTful view contextual filter to use path alias

Tags: views

I have created a RESTful view in Drupal 8, there I need to display a few of node contents by node alias in contextual filter.

View URL: `www.example.com/api/book-details/{node-alias}`

Instead of node alias if I use node ID, it's working fine. For example: `api/book-details/100` (node ID 100) is working fine.

URL alias for node 100 is "first-content". So how do I fetch details using node alias in contextual filter? For example: `api/book-details/first-content` (this is not giving any result).

Comment: @NoSssweat Couldn't able to see path in contextual filter? Can you please elaborate more or provide some example?

Comment: nvm it's not available. I guess you will have to create a custom contextual filter. See [How to Create a Custom Views Argument Plugin in Drupal 8](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/how-create-custom-views-argument-plugin-drupal-8)

Answer (score 0):

As No Sssweat already mentioned in his comment there is no Contextual filter available for path aliases, you can try to create your own (and share on drupal.org while you're at it :) ).

But if you have set your aliases based on node Titles then you may get away with using `Content: Title` as your contextual filter.

Just be careful about the `Case in Path` setting and you'll probably need `Transform spaces to dashes in URL` under `More`.